# Prevent background image flashing on change

Tags: css, background-image

I'm using background image for a button and switch to a different one on `:hover`.

When the switch happens on the first mouse over it briefly flashes the background color. (I set it to orange here so it's more noticeable, it does the same with white background, or if I leave the background color unset). However, it does not flash on subsequent mouseovers.

How can I prevent the first flash of the background color that happens on page load, and first mouseover?

https://codepen.io/ClayN/pen/EeeRyP

```css
.backgroundbutton {
  background-image: url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background.jpg');
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.backgroundbutton:hover {
  background-image: url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background2.jpg')
}
```

```html
<a class="backgroundbutton">hover over me</a>
```

Comment: What about setting ``background-color: transparent``  ??

Comment: @AXL  Doesn't work. I just get the page color (whatever is behind the transparent button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load both images using multiple background and make the first one on the top then adjust `background-size` to show the other on hover. In this case, both images will be loaded initially and the second one will be ready on hover:

```css
.backgroundbutton {
  background-image: 
   url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background.jpg'),
   url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background2.jpg');
  background-size:auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.backgroundbutton:hover {
  background-size:0 0,auto;
}
```

```html
<a class="backgroundbutton">  hover over me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the hover background image will not be pre-loaded, so that it shows the flashing effects especially for larger image size and longer loading time.

It can be fixed easily by using CSS sprites, e.g. combine the 2 background images into 1, and change the `background-position` on `:hover`, say the [new image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GATzU.png) is 400px (200+200) height.

And, don't set any `background-color` to stop the initial flashing of the background color on page load. Also, `width` and `height` won't apply to inline-level `a` tag unless you change it to `display: inline-block` or `block` etc.

```css
.backgroundbutton {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/GATzU.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.backgroundbutton:hover {
  background-position: 0 -200px;
}
```

```html
<a class="backgroundbutton">hover over me</a>
```

In addition, you don't need any images for gradient background, e.g.:

```css
.backgroundbutton {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #999, #fff);
}

.backgroundbutton:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #fff);
}
```

```html
<a class="backgroundbutton">hover over me</a>
```