# Smoother background-images animations (prevent flickering)

Tags: html, css

I have three background images that I want to animate between. I do this as outlined below.

However, I find that sometimes (when first loading the page), the images flicker. So instead of a smooth transition what happens is that image 1 flickers then smoothly fades out, then image 2 flickers and then smoothly transitions in.

How can I avoid this flickering? Is there a way to wait for the images to be fully loaded before to start the animation? Or is that not the problem?

```
.page-light {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .page-light {
  background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-mobile.png');
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768.00px) {
  .page-light {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-1.png');
    -webkit-animation: animation-home-background 9000ms infinite;
    -moz-animation: animation-home-background 9000ms infinite;
    -o-animation: animation-home-background 9000ms infinite;
    animation: animation-home-background 9000ms infinite;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}



@-webkit-keyframes animation-home-background {
  0% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-1.png');
  }
  40% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-2.png');
  }
  80% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-3.png');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-1.png');
  }
}

@keyframes animation-home-background {
  0% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-1.png');
  }
  33% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-2.png');
  }
  66% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-3.png');
  }
  100% {
    background-image: url('/img/hero/front-introduction-1.png');
  }
}
```

Comment: how would we help without knowing your `HTML` structure ?

Comment: <body class="page-light"> bootstrap content here </body>

Comment: You should consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358175/prevent-background-image-flashing-on-change/52358326#52358326) approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be extremely helpful, as pointed out by @vxpin in the comments.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358326/4262057

Basically you preload all the images as follows:

```
.stylename {
  background-image: 
   url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background.jpg'),
   url('http://www.BungalowSoftware.com/images/silver-background2.jpg');
}
```