# Avoid white flash when changing background image on select drop-down changes

Tags: javascript, css, image, background-image, prefetch

How to avoid white flash when changing background image on the select option? Below is what I tried:

```html
<div
  id="landmarkimg"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + landmarkImage + ')'}"
  class="background "
></div>
<select (change)="countrySelected($event)" class="" [(ngModel)]="cid">
  <option value="0">Select your country</option>
  <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [ngValue]="c.value">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**ts:**

```js
countrySelected(event) {
    let cname = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].text;
    if (cname == 1) {
        this.landmarkImage = '/assets/images/1.jpg';
    }
    if (cname == 2) {
        this.landmarkImage = '/assets/images/2.jpg';
    }
}
```

Background Image is changing on the select drop-down, but there is some `white flash` between changes. How can I avoid that? There are 10 images, they are changing on click of `option`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52358326/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762176/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am changing bg image on select change, how above link can help? Please explain it to me.

Comment: you are having flash because the browser need to load the image ... I show you 2 different question to avoid this by initially loading the image so they are ready and you will not get any flash (check both links and try the different snippet)

Comment: @TemaniAfif both are via CSS, you can see. I am using java-script.

Comment: I know both are via CSS (I provided both solutions) and this is the main trick. You preload the images using CSS so they are ready when changing them using JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually, I am trying to do this in Angular, so what I did: I loaded all images in `index.html` using `html: before {}` and changing image in `app.config.ts`, but still white flash is there. :(